# How can I subscribe to the weekly newsletter?

Tags: support

On Meta Stack Exchange, it is suggested that [I can subscribe to a site's weekly newsletter from the User Edit Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121631/how-do-i-subscribe-for-a-sites-weekly-email-newsletter). However, I couldn't find such an option on the new profile page that was rolled out recently. <strike>Furthermore, Mythology is missing from the [newsletters page on stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters)</strike> Yay, Mythology now shows up in the list (under Culture).

How can I subscribe to our newsletter?

Answer (score 4):

From the other SE sites, I think the links to the "Subscribe to the weekly newsletter" page is formed as follow: `http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=` + URL of site.

Meaning the canonical link for ours should be: http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=mythology.stackexchange.com

And indeed it seems to work:

[image: Screenshot of the page]